# Weight not set while creating content experiment through google analytics api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, content-experiments

I am trying to create Google Analytics content experiment dynamically with 3 variations using API with [insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/experiments/insert) method. The experiment is created successfully and it also shows up in GA UI with status as **Running**. However, when I try to use this experiment to select which variation to show, it everytime gives me 0 variation.

When I try to view the experiment using [GET](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/experiments/get) method, it shows me all the experiment details but the weights of all variations are 0. I suspect this is the reason why I always get variation 0 when I run this experiment.

Again when I create the experiment manually through GA UI with 4 variations, it sets the weight of all variations to 0.25.

When I try to set the weight of the variations while dynamically creating the experiment, I get the error 'cannot set value of weight as it is a readonly property'.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Did you work out a solution?

Comment: I did not get any solution to this.

Comment: I've spent a good bit of time on it and can't find a solution. To get round the problem I'm going to change the `ServingFramework` to `API`, handle the variation choice myself and then send the experiment data back to Google using api.js.

Comment: [There is an open issue on this.](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=377) If you subscribe to that then you'll get notified when it's fixed.

Comment: The issue is created by my teammate only.

Comment: I've posted a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150031/google-analytics-experiments-always-chooses-original-variation/20406804).